# How to get content from tag with certian class in Selenium in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm web scraping a website with Selenium Webdriver in JS and I want to get the count of `<tr>` tags that have exactly three children.

```
<tr>
 <td>One</td>
 <td>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>One</td>
 <td>Two</td>
 <td>Three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>One</td>
 <td>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>One</td>
 <td>Two</td>
 <td>Three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>One</td>
 <td>Two</td>
 <td>Three</td>
 <td>Four</td>
</tr>
```

The result is: 2 tags that have exactly three `<td>` child nodes

I want to write a xPath line but I do not know how, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below XPath for `tr` nodes with 3 child `td` nodes:

```
//tr[count(td)=3]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Xpath** ::List<**WebElement**>text=driver.findElements(**By.xpath("//td[text()='Three']")**);

```
    System.out.println(text.size());
```

Comment: This won't return required `tr` nodes. And this is not even JavaScript...